# Optimization by avoiding object duplication?

Tags: java, memory, optimization, static

I'm wondering if by avoiding the duplication of an array by accessing it through the main class is an optimization worth doing.

This may be a fundamental concept that I am missing, if so then I apologize for the poor interpretation on my end.

```
public class Sinebow {

private int c = -1;
private final int t;

public Sinebow() {
    this.t = (RainbowGear.rb.length - 2);
}
public Color getNext() {
    if (c > t)
        c = -1;
    c++;
    return RainbowGear.rb[c];
    }
}
```

The above class is created a few times and stored in a `HashMap` in the main class. Previously a `SineBow` was initialized like so:

```
public Sinebow(Color[] init){
    this.<local_color[]_var> = init;
    this.t = (init.length - 2);
}
```

Essentially a copy of the static `Color` array was passed into each instance of a `SineBow`.

```
public static Color[] rb = new Color[64];
```

The array does not change, it is filled on start up and does not change through the program.

I'm almost 99% sure that accessing the single `Color` array from each `SineBow` instance results in no additional copies of the array in memory, however I'm only 75% certain that there is no processing implications because of the 'optimization'.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't see the point, if the array of colors is constant, make it a constant in `Sinebow`

Comment: @RC. Sinebow is an object that is initialized several times and stored into a HashMap, so storing the same color array with 64 elements, several times, is a waste of resources. Albeit being rather minor, it's primarily the practice that i'd like to improve upon - hence the question confirming my interpretation of the concept.

Comment: Java passes references, not copies. So all your Sinebow instances have a reference to the same array (unless you're making an explicit copy). A reference costs 4 bytes.

Comment: @JBNizet private Color[] init; inside SineBow. It was being set to the  array passed to it on initialization.

Comment: Yes. The caller passes a reference to the array to the constructor, and the object keeps a reference to this array. Only a reference is passed. A pointer, if you prefer. Only one array is in memory, and several references point to this array. Each reference takes 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the array does not change anywhere within your application, you're good. You can be 100% sure that you are working off of only one main copy. There are no processing implications of this either - just be careful that using static often and not keeping track can lead to sloppy code but if the values do not need changing anywhere, then it's fine.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer!